# What framework to use for a java web app

Tags: java, web-applications

I need to develop a single page Web app. The app is currently programmed in java and displays a graph based on the users preferences. But it needs porting to a website. So I need to display it on a page, but not as a java applet. The java app accepts arguments that can be used to make new calculations based on the users requirements and output them to a text file.

The requirements for the project are: not displayed as a java applet, no calculations done on the clients side and the app is placed in line with other html code.

The calculations *could* be done client side as long as there are no ways that the mathematics is visible. Nor can it be easily found.

I've looked at using node.js as the backend. Displaying a Web form that sends the inputted data as a json, server converts it to xml and then runs the java app and it loads in the xml. Java does the calculations and saves the data points as a txt file and sends it back to the client. However, this seems long winded and not the best way to do it. I'm also unsure on how to then go about the user making changes to the requirements and updating the graph. Id like the app to be as efficient as possible and stable when handling multiple connections.

Hopefully this makes sense. I'm looking for any kind of guidance on languages, frameworks and some kind of design tips please!

Comment: The best framework for this is Spring

Comment: What's wrong with plain javascript?

Comment: The requirements state that it cannot be displayed as a java applet

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely distinct languages. Java applets are out of fashion. JavaScript in the browser, on the other hand, is unambiguousy mainstream.

Answer (score 0):

U can use Node.Js for singal page web application.

Answer (score 0):

I did not read your full description of the question prior to submit an equivocated answer. But now I got what you want.

So what I would suggest to you is split the Frontend from Backend.

About the frontend you want to build a page with HTML + CSS + Javascript. If your app is complex (eg. more than one screen, modals, bunch of different UI components etc) you wanna use some framework like Angular or React, if it's not you can keep with the holy jQuery and you will be fine. Said that, you will post every request to your backend using AJAX.

Now about the backend: actually I'm writing this because you said that you want a backend, but you also said the requirement is to have all the calcs in frontend, well you need to check if you really need to persist data, process business rules etc. If the answer is yes, you will need a backend. For backend you can choose your team favorite language, which can be Java, Python, PHP, Node.js, Ruby, etc. It's up to you.

Forget about XML, you are going to post objects from the frontend in JSON, unless for some reason you are required to have XML. And then your backend will easily reply JSON data. There are some good frameworks for backend: Dropwizard, Springboot and Play for Java, Flask or Django for Python, Laravel for PHP, Express for Node.js, Rails for Ruby.

You can easily achieve what you need using the above directions. All of these frameworks in frontend and backend, are designed to integrate like that.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js and other scripting languages has their own advantage in terms of performance and scalabilty.If you have single page application and there are future chances it could be extended,then you should MVC frameworks like Struts and Spring. According to me spring is really very advanced and has some really good integration with charts and graphs. You can also use json as response with Spring as micro service so that you can saggrigate the UI part with Application part and remove the dependency of technologies.